# Get ID of children Element on click

Tags: angular, typescript, events, routes, router

I am trying to get the id of a children component's element.

```
<navigation (click)="resetRoute($event)"></navigation
```

In the navigation component there is a list with routerLinks. Each item has an id.

```
resetRoute(event) {
  const elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;
  console.log(elementId);
  console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.id);
  console.log(event.target.attributs.id);
}
```

All of them return blank or undefined. I am using Angular v10 and TypeScript 4.0.5

In my routing.module.ts: There is a wildcard to another component (e.g Component A).

My goal is to get the route of the children element (e.g. Component B) and navigate to it.

How can I do it? Has anyone a solution out there?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it.

```
resetRoute() {
  const url: string = this.router.url.replace('/oldParam', '/newParam');
  this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```

The new url ist {baseURI]/newParam/{eventParam}.
The eventParam is set with the click-function